# C# smtp - does it retry

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

My question is, when using C# and using a smtp client to send email, does the smtp class retry deferred emails?

I know Outlook / Gmail etc will retry emails if they defer or can't send straight away.

If you just write some C# code and use the smtp client to send email does it perform retries as gmail etc does?

I will be using the smtp client and passing in an external smtp authentication details. E.g. Duo circle

Comment: No. Retry would have to be implemented in your application.

Comment: SmtpClient itself does not retry, but relay smtp server you are sending it to (to which you provide credentials) will retry if necessary.